# HapiJS error handling

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I have created error instances like this:

```
class InsufficientScope extends Error {
  constructor(resource = false) {
    const errorMessage = resource
      ? 'User does not have enough privileges to access this resource.'
      : `User does not have enough privileges to access the ${resource}`;

    super(errorMessage);

    this.type = 'authorization_error';
    this.statusCode = '403';
  }
}
```

When I throw these errors in my handler like return `reply(new InsufficientScope());`, it is always transformed to a Boom object somehow. Is every error thrown inside Hapi, transformed to a Boom object with it's properties?

Because I want to be able to specify behaviour for some specific errors (i.e. logging yes/no etc.) via the onPreResponse extension point. But I cannot really make a difference wether it's my own error or it's an error thrown by Hapi, because they all look the same.

I also cannot do things like:

```
if (req.response instanceof InsufficientScope) {
 // do something
}
```

I also cannot use `Boom.create` because that will not be an instance but just a plain object.

Answer (score 0):

you can do in two ways 
1)reply(null,new InsufficientScope())
2)onPreresponse hook you can  do like this

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', (request, reply) => {
  if((request.response.isBoom)
  {
   return reply(null,new InsufficientScope())
   }
  return reply.continue();
})
```